# Changing text of file without corrupting uninstall process

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have custom action which executes `Before="InstallFinalize"` and replace text in config file(config.asp):

```
String configFilePath = session.CustomActionData["configFile"];
var configFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(configFilePath);            
session.Log("replace config file");
configFile.Replace("test2", "test");
session.Log("write config file");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(configFilePath, configFile);
```

When I try to uninstall the application, I get error:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\myProject\config.asp'.
```

But the file is there. I guess it is problem, because i have changed the original one?
How should i change in my code that changing file wont corrupt uninstall process?
Should i change the execute sequence when changing the file?

Answer (score 1):

The easy resolution to this is to install the config.asp file as `config.asp.template` and make a copy of it to `config.asp` as part of the custom action changing the bits you need.

That way the original file is never touched and will uninstall correctly.

Comment: That is indeed very easy resolution. After harvesting the folder I will have to change the file name inside the created file (with batch script).
I'm curious how to do that with only one file, but nevertheless, this solution will satisfy my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Don't harvest it, just statically include it in your Wix project. I usually only ever harvest files manually and then include that output in my project. From then on adding/removing the odd file here and there isn't an issue.